# Delete upstream branch and propagate downstream?

Tags: git, github

We have a LOT of branches in our upstream repo and we all work using the Forks workflow (like open source development) so we each have a fork of this heinously branched upstream repo. I'm about to start deleting stale branches from upstream (some are >7000 commits behind master) but I'm hoping there's a way to propagate those branch deletions downstream to our forks. Is this possible or does it fundamentally violate the capabilities of git?

**EDIT:** To clarify, each developer has their own fork, which has a remote on Github. So there is an upstream remote, a downstream remote, and a downstream local repo. Nobody should be working in a local version of upstream. Everyone pushes local work to their downstream remote repo and opens PRs from there.

Answer (score 1):

Downstream you will have to run `git fetch --prune` in order to see those remote branches go away.

Comment: But those branches aren't actually gone in the downstream remote. `git prune` only works to remove local branches that are tracking the upstream remote.

Comment: aahhh..... I didn't say `git prune`. I said `git fetch --prune`. That will eliminate the remote references of the branches that no longer exist on those remotes that are being fetched.

Comment: I think I didn't fully describe our workflow. The remote that I push to is my fork (on github). Even after deleting all the extra branches on the upstream remote (and getting rid of the local upstream branches using `git fetch upstream --prune`, my remote fork still has all those branches!

Comment: Well... in that case you have to push delitions for those branches: `git push my-remote :branch1 :branch2 :branch3`. That will delete branch1, branch2 and branch3. Can it be done without you having to write every single branch there? You might try to produce a list of branches and then use xargs to get them on a single command... but then the question is not about git anymore, but about bash.